# CocoaPods Header file not found

Tags: cocoapods

I have and iOS project using a third party cocoapod spec. My problem is that when I try to build my project, it says header no found. Here is the way my Pods are organized:

Podfile Directory:

1. Podfile:

   - SampleSpec
   - - Header1.h
   - - Subfolder1
   - - - Header2.h

**Header1 imports Header2 using #import "/Subfolder1/Header2.h"

The problem is whenever I import Header1 in my code, it always fails in building. Does anybody encountered the same problem with cocoapod?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the expanded file structure of your pod?

Comment: Hi! Here's the screenshot of my Pods directory
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kkxvhetw9mqpg4n/Screen%20Shot%202014-07-25%20at%2012.51.24%20PM.png

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve this one. Just found out that there's a header_mappings_dir option that you can set in you spec file to preserve the folder structure of the directory that contains your public header files.